# How to resolve the error while saving into a parquet file?

Tags: python, parquet

While saving a pandas dataframe to parquet, I got this below error

ArrowImplementedError: Unsupported cast from dictionary

Comment: Hello, can you provide a [mre] of your code so we can try to see what your problem is ? It is really hard to help you without it.

Comment: Dataframe.to_parquet("filename.parquet") So when i try to execute this line, I get that ArrowNotImplementedError. The dataframe has column of type float64,object,datetime, category